# Fingerprint on Java Web Start

Tags: java, security, java-web-start, fingerprint, accesscontrolexception

When I start my application I get the following message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.Matcher.<clinit>(Matcher.java:8)
    at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.processing._impl.DPFPEnrollmentFactoryImpl$EnrollmentImpl.<init>(DPFPEnrollmentFactoryImpl.java:40)
    at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.processing._impl.DPFPEnrollmentFactoryImpl.createEnrollment(DPFPEnrollmentFactoryImpl.java:20)
    at Formularios.CapturaHuella.<init>(CapturaHuella.java:245)
    at Formularios.CapturaHuella$10.run(CapturaHuella.java:561)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "loadLibrary.otmcjni")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkLink(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.digitalpersona.onetouch.jni.MatchingLibrary.<clinit>(MatchingLibrary.java:16)

... 19 more
```

Comment: Are you prompted to accept the digitally signed code?

Answer (score 2):

It means you don't have installed the fingerprint driver:

http://www.digitalpersona.com/support/downloads/software-updates/reader-engine/

Answer (score 0):

typically this is happening when you have some static initialization block and there is something wrong - mostly due to NullPointerException. try to debug this initialization block carefully

Answer (score 0):

The *AccessControlException* states that you do not have permission to load the DLL **otmcjni.dll** into your Java process.

Make sure that you have *signed* your JAR file.

Comment: Hi, yes I signed my jar and the all jars of folder "lib/" for example: dpfpenrollment.jar, dpfpverification.jar, dpotapi.jar, depotjni.jar.